# Common EOMONTH formula for all the months in a year that show a date to the end date of quarter?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

There are many dates listed of different different months of a year. I want a common formula of EOMONTH which returns to me the end date of ecah quarters respectively to the date mentioned above.
eg: 2-march-2020 should give me the result 31st March 2020.
and 5-january-2020 should also give me the date 31st march 2020.

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
=EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(A1), (QUOTIENT(MONTH(A1)-1,3)+1)*3, 1), 0)
```